# Is "hystrix.shareSecurityContext" secure to use for sharing SecurityContextHolder attributes?

Tags: oauth-2.0, hystrix, thread-local, feign

In my application, I need to use Feign client with Oauth2 token. However, hystrix executes feign operation in another thread and due to SecurityContextHolder is threadLocal my application could not get the required value. Therefore, after some research I found that "hystrix.shareSecurityContext" config param provides to share this threadlocal objects in hystrix threads. And it worked.

However, is it secure to use this config param? Is there any possibility that threadLocal objects end up in another wrong thread under high traffic? How can i verify that threadLocal objecst are shared within only correct hystrix threads? Because not related hystrix threads should not get these tokens because of this config param.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any updates on this?